# Remainder problem using MOD

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

What's the remainder when $ 43^{101} + 23^{101}$ is divided by 66?

If we use the remainder obtained when $ 43^{101} + 23^{101}$ is divided by $66$, then it becomes, 
$$13^{101}+23^{101}$$ then how can I use further MOD?

Comment: $43^{101} + 23^{101}$ is divisible by $43 + 23 = 66$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $43\equiv -23\pmod{66}$. What happens when you raise $-1$ to an odd power?

Hint for a different approach. Do you know how the polynomial $x^n+y^n$ is divisible by $x+y$?